# Call requires api level in non android modules

Tags: android-studio, java-8, lint

I'm getting `call requires api level X` in non-android modules when using Java 8 features.
How to remove it.
Suppressing with annotation doesn't seem the right way to me

Comment: Did you resolve this? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78382 looks related.

Comment: post your gradle files and code so that SO members can reproduce the same behavior , simply follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) plus details about studio , JDK versions though bug report ( link by Giszmo ) seems compelling

Comment: post your code and gradle

Comment: I don't even remember where it was now

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

> Android supports all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.
>
> Support for Java 8 language features requires a new compiler called Jack. Jack is supported only on Android Studio 2.1 and higher.
>
> Android does not support all Java 8 language features. However, the following features are available when developing apps targeting Android 7.0 **(API level 24)**:
>
> - Default and static interface methods
> - Lambda expressions (also available on API level 23 and lower)
> - Repeatable annotations
> - Method References (also available on API level 23 and lower)
> - Type Annotations (also available on API level 23 and lower)

... emphasis by me.

Comment: Ups, now I did understand you are not asking about Android modules... so how do you use those? If you integrate them into the Android application, they still must obey the rules above, even if they are not calling any Android API, but they will be run by Android OS JVM. If you are using them only on normal full-fledged JVM supporting Java8 (like JUnit tests running on host OS) (so that code will not land into .apk), just switch off lint as emergency solution. Although I wonder if it shouldn't be intelligent enough to realize you are not using Java8 with Android code.

Comment: Not the OP here. In my project it is complaining about "Call requires API level 9 (current min is 1)" on a library module we use on an app with min API 14.

Comment: @Giszmo how is that Java8 related? If particular API call is in question, then that's different lint check I think? Why your build process thinks it's in "current minSdk=1": I don't know, google, or post question with full details (build scripts, project definition, etc). But I don't see connection of your problem to Java8 features.